# how to get the first number in a string using a regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the first number and only the first number from a string. The solutions I have found find all the numbers.

I have tried playing around with the code below but haven't figured it out.

```
/\d./g
```

I have a string like this IN9000 and I want to get only the 9. The string will have different values for the third position in a string.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `g` (global) flag:

```
/\d/
```

Comment: also remove the dot

Comment: When I run this on an online tester. It says a match isn't found. This regular expression will be used in my JavaScript code. Does that matter?

Comment: @User123 Note that the slashes are *not* part of the regex - they are delimiters used by your langauge, but I put them in for consistency with how you coded the regex in your question. Try just `\d` in the online tool.